# Problemas no css, menu não funciona

Tags: html, css

Simplesmente não funciona, não aparece as "li".

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style>

/* reset do html */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, span,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-weight: inherit;
 font-style: inherit;
 font-size: 100%;
 font-family: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
 position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
 color: black;
 background:#fff url("Scr/fundoClaro.png") repeat;
 text-align:center; /* hack para o IE */  
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 18px;
 color: #333333;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin: 0 0 60px;
}

div {display:block;}

input {
 position:absolute;
 display:none
}
label {
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
 display:inline-block;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:1px;
 padding-top:0;
 padding-left:0;
 font-size:13px;
 line-height:45px;
 cursor:pointer
}
label span {
 display:block;
 padding:5px;
 background:rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)
}
label span span {
 padding:0 20px;
 background:transparent;
 transition:background .3s, color .4s;
 -o-transition:background .3s, color .4s;
 -ms-transition:background .3s, color .4s;
 -moz-transition:background .3s, color .4s;
 -webkit-transition:background .3s, color .4s
}
label:hover span span {
 background:#3498db;
 color:#fff
}
input:checked + label span span {
 background:#3498db;
 color:#fff
}
ul {
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 font-size:13px
}
ul > li {
 
 opacity:0;
 
}
.menu > .aba-1:checked ~ .caixa ul .aba-1,
.menu > .aba-1:checked ~ .caixa ul .aba-2,
.menu > .aba-1:checked ~ .caixa ul .aba-3,
.menu > .aba-1:checked ~ .caixa ul .aba-4 {
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
 opacity:1
}
.conteudo {
 width:600px;
 position:relative;
 line-height:20px
}
.pagina-url {
 float:right;
 margin-top:15px
}
.topo {
 width:1170px;
 position:relative;
 float:top;
 height: 40px;
 top:0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="topo">
  <div class="menu">
   <input type="radio" name="menu" checked id="aba-inicio" class="aba-inicio">
       <label for="aba-inicio"><span><span>Inicio</span></span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="menu" id="aba-app" class="aba-app">
       <label for="aba-app"><span><span>APP</span></span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="menu" id="aba-informacao" class="aba-informacao">
       <label for="aba-informacao"><span><span>Informações</span></span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="menu" id="aba-contato" class="aba-contato">
       <label for="aba-contato"><span><span>Contato</span></span></label>
      <input type="radio" name="menu" id="aba-download" class="aba-download">
       <label for="aba-download"><span><span class="importante">Baixe agora</span></span></label> 
  </div>
  
 </div>
 <div class="caixa">
  <ul>
   <li class="aba-1">
    <div class="conteudo">
     conteudo 1
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="aba-2">
    <div class="conteudo">
     conteudo 2
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="aba-3">
    <div class="conteudo">
     conteudo 3
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="aba-4">
    <div class="conteudo">
     conteudo 4
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você colocou a opacity (transparência) dos `<li>` como `0`. Mude para `1` ou remova essa parte do CSS.

```
ul > li {       
    opacity:0;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, não é um "problema" no CSS, na verdade ele esta cumprindo exatamente o que você escreveu, pois foi definido dentro da declaração que a propriedade opacity recebe valor 0. O valor da propriedade opacity vai de 0 à 1, podendo assumir valores como: 0.1, 0.2, ... 0.9, 1. Sendo assim bastaria trocar seu valor de 0 para 1 e as "li's" voltaria a aparecer.
Ex.:

```
ul > li {
    opacity: 1;
}
```